# How to get the exact height of a listView

Tags: android, listview, view

In my layout i have a scrollView and inside it there are two listViews. I used the below posted code to get the height of the listviews, and that code returned the height correctly.

But regarding the second listview, i used the same code,but it returns very large value larger than the height of the listview.

please let me know why i am getting very large value for the listview height and how to get the exact height of the listview correctly?

**code**:

```
case R.id.versicherungsListeActivity2mod_lisVie_meineDocs:      

            heightInPIX = (int) this.calcListViewItemsHeight(listView);

            param = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, heightInPIX );
            param.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, ruleSubject);
            container.setLayoutParams(param);
            listView.requestLayout();
            break;
    ....
    ....
    ....
    private float calcListViewItemsHeight(ListView listView) {
    Log.d(TAG, getApplicationContext().getResources().getResourceEntryName(listView.getId()) + ".getCount() :" + listView.getCount());

    int height = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < listView.getCount(); i++) {
        View childView = listView.getAdapter().getView(i, null, listView);
        childView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
        height+= childView.getMeasuredHeight();
    }

    //dividers height
    height += listView.getDividerHeight() * listView.getCount();

    return height;
}
```

**layout**:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/versicherungsListeActivity2mod_linLay_verDetailsList_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/versicherungslistsactivity2mod_linLay_detailsBar_container"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/versicherungsListeActivity2mod_lisVie_versDetails"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"></ListView>

        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You're doing a conversion from `dp` to `px` on the `height` value. Don't do that. It's already in `px`.

Comment: @MikeM. please have a look a the code again..i corrected it and still i have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Try This code:

```
LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) mListView.getLayoutParams();
lp.height = 300;
mListView.setLayoutParams(params);
```